# Are the locations text messages are sent from logged?

Tags: phone, smartphone, simcard

When you send a text message from a phone with a sim card, is there a log which records your location at the moment, or any other information? is it linked to the phone? to the sim card? to both?

Answer (score 1):

The GPS location might not be logged, but the phone company will have a log of which tower you were connected to at the time. This log will include the SIM info as well as the IMSI, which would be tied to both the SIM and the device.